# How to supply images to documents unpacked by l3build

Tags: graphics, l3build

I have an module that I want to manage with l3build.  Unpacking a docstrip file generates a tex file.  `l3build doc` typesets that generated tex file.  But I can't figure out how to configure `build.lua` to enable that process to see any images that should be included.

My MWE is four files (all in a [Github repo](https://github.com/leingang/test-l3build-doc-images/tree/master) for ease)

**file tree**

```
├── build.lua
├── foo.dtx
├── foo.ins
└── support
    └── duck.png
```

**`foo.dtx`**

```
%<*foo>
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\includegraphics[
    width=\textwidth,
%<bar>angle=180,
]{duck}
\end{document}
%</foo>
```

**`foo.ins`**

```
\input docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{\file{bar.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{foo,bar}}}
\endbatchfile
```

So `bar.tex` has one extra line, which should rotate the image 180
degrees.

**`build.lua`**

```
module = "foo"

typesetsuppfiles = {"duck.png"}
typesetfiles = {"foo.dtx","bar.tex"}
```

**duck.png**

[image: duck]

Command:

```
l3build doc foo
```

- `duck.png` is copied into `typesetdir`
- `foo.dtx` is typeset in `typesetdir` (I think)
- result: success.  `foo.pdf` is moved into `maindir`.

Command:

```
l3build doc bar
```

- `bar.tex` is unpacked into `unpackdir`
- `tex` is run on `bar.tex` in `unpackdir`
- result: failure because `duck.png` is not found.

Comment: Add `duck.png` in `support/`.

Comment: Hmm, I see where the issue arises ... need to think about a solution

Comment: @JosephWright the setup works fine for me if I set `typesetfiles = {"*.dtx"}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I know :) It's to do with what gets copied where: there's an assumption that images or whatever go with 'real' sources, not with extracted demos. I think I may have to make an adjustment to `l3build` to address this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it appears my example is too minimal.  I don't want to typeset `foo.dtx`; I want to unpack several tex files from it and typeset those.  I will work on revising the example.

Comment: My latest version of the question seems to isolate my issue better.

Comment: @JosephWright Should I open an issue on the l3build github?

Comment: Please: it might be a few days, but Marcel and I know we have a few issues to look at and fix

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks to you and Marcel for fixing the issue.  I added a CW self-answer to close out this question.  if you would rather write your own I'll accept that one instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/latex3/l3build/issues/210) to the l3build github and it has been fixed.  Thanks Joseph and Marcel!

Answer (score 1):

This should be your `build.lua`:

```lua
module = "foo"

typesetsuppfiles = { "duck.png" }
typesetfiles = {"foo.dtx"}
```

and the directory structure should be:

```
├── build.lua
├── foo.dtx
├── foo.ins
└── support
    └── duck.png
```

`support` is the official directory name supported by the `l3build` program.

Comment: What I understood from the documentation is that `support` is the *default* directory name, and it could be changed.  But I did as you suggested with moving the image file and removing the `supportdir` line.  The bigger issue is that I don't want to typeset `foo.dtx`, I want to typeset `foo.tex`.  In my actual use case unpacking `foo.dtx` generates several different tex files.

Comment: I have a better version of my MWE now.

Answer (score 0):

The following code (yes it's ugly) works for the specific case you present:

```lua
module = "foo"

--typesetsuppfiles = {"duck.png"}
typesetfiles = {"foo.dtx","bar.tex"}

function docinit_hook()
  errorlevel = cp("duck.png", "./support", unpackdir)
  if errorlevel ~= 0 then
    error("** Error!!: Can't copy duck.png from ./support to "..unpackdir)
    return errorlevel
  end
  errorlevel = cp("duck.png", "./support", typesetdir)
  if errorlevel ~= 0 then
    error("** Error!!: Can't copy duck.png from ./support to "..typesetdir)
    return errorlevel
  end
  return 0
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've been reading through your [demopkg\-jw](https://github.com/pablgonz/demopkg-jw) repo so I recognize your code.  I think this could be cleaned up using some of the pattens in l3build's modules, so that every file in `supportdir` that matches a pattern in `typdsetsuppfiles` is copied into `unpackdir` and `typesetdir`.  But I think that's what `build/local` is really _for_.